# Train Travel to Woodbury Outlet

Tags: trains, public-transport, new-york-city, new-york-state

I am in Brooklyn and planning to go to Woodbury Outlet in Central Valley, NY. How can I go there by train if possible.

Comment: @choster I would like to mark it as a solution if you don't mind.

Comment: There are many Cab operators who operate in Harriman, if you are traveling in a group its $5 per person one way from the Station to the Outlets or back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When visiting an establishment, it is always good to check with them first for any transportation recommendations. In this case, the [travel to Woodbury Common](http://www.premiumoutlets.com/outlet/woodbury-common/travel-here) page has many sets of directions and links for various modes. They include a link to an official MTA page on [getting out to Woodbury Common Premium Outlets](http://web.mta.info/mnr/html/getaways/outbound_woodbury_commons.htm).

You can do it in as few as two transfers from Brooklyn. You can take the New York City Subway to Penn Station, then any New Jersey Transit train to Secaucus Junction, then a Port Jervis Line (New Jersey Main Line) train to Harriman. You could also take the subway to World Trade Center, then the PATH train to Hoboken, and board a Port Jervis Line train from there. Once in Harriman, however, you'll need to call a taxi.

Comment: This is a good answer, I would however recommend taking a bus from PABT to Woodbury Commons if you're traveling from NYC, specially on weekends when the frequency of the Port Jervis line is not too good.

Comment: Bus details / tickets here. $30 round trip. https://www.busbud.com/en/bus-new-york-woodbury/r/dr5reg-dr7b20 (Full disclosure: I work on this project.)